Kafka Streams KTable Aggregation expected Behavior with Tombstone?
Quick question on kafka streams KTable Aggregation.
Let say we have 3 input messages/record in our input KTable, which when grouped yield to 1 group of 3 elements, which then yield to one aggregated Record.

If a tombstone for one of the input message/record is sent to the KTable, to keep things short, this will remove the record from the group, and trigger the substractor downstream, giving the opportunity to update the Aggregated Record by removing anything related to that record.

A) My question is, when we sent a tombstone for all 3 records, and they are all removed from the group, meaning the group does not exist anymore, aside from the 3 substractor  operation being triggers, shall we expected that a tombstone record should be emitted for the aggregated record automatically ? or is it something that must be done in the substractor logic somehow.

(A-1) Said differently, does the resulting KTable of an Aggregation, emit a Tombstone Record for any of its Aggregated record for which the input Group has been emptied ( i.e. does not exist anymore) ?
(A-2) Or is it that if we want to see a Tombstone Record emitted it must be created in the substractor by a user logic, that could detect we are substracting the last record of the aggregation and therefore the new Aggregate returned  should be (Key, Null)

